# Kdevelop4 path to library binaries

Tags: kdevelop, kdevelop4

I'm having problem reported as below while trying to execute it. Where should I go to let it know where to find the .so lib which is under ${HOME}/projects/OpenImageIO/dist/linux64/lib?

Starting: /home/chaoren/Dropbox/hw2/hw2_3
/home/chaoren/Dropbox/hw2/hw2_3: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenImageIO.so.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I built this project by importing my Makefile

```
OFILES = Matrix.o LinearAlgebra.o PerlinNoise.o Camera.o OIIOFiles.o Image.o Utilities.o Grid.o SparceGrid.o VolumeOperations.o Ray.o Face.o Line.o Lights.o Group.o PolySurf.o File.o OBJFile.o Vector.o

AFILES = $(OFILES)

ROOTDIR = .

LIB = $(ROOTDIR)/libVR.a

LINKS =  Magick++-config  --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs -lm -lOpenImageIO -L/usr/local/lib -L${HOME}/projects/OpenImageIO/dist/linux64/lib

INCLUDES = Magick++-config  --cppflags --cxxflags -I${HOME}/projects/OpenImageIO/dist/linux64/include

CXX = g++ -Wall -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -fopenmp

.C.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(INCLUDES) $<

all: $(AFILES)
    ar rv $(LIB) $?

hw2_1:  hw2_1.C
    $(CXX) hw2_1.C $(INCLUDES) $(LIB) $(LINKS) -o hw2_1

hw2_2:  hw2_2.C
    $(CXX) hw2_2.C $(INCLUDES) $(LIB) $(LINKS) -o hw2_2

hw2_3:  hw2_3.C
    $(CXX) hw2_3.C $(INCLUDES) $(LIB) $(LINKS) -o hw2_3

noiseimage:  noiseimage.C
    $(CXX) noiseimage.C $(INCLUDES) $(LIB) $(LINKS) -o noiseimage

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.gch core $(LIB) vr vrppm *~ vRender hw2_1 hw_2 hw2_3
```

Answer (score 0):

KDevelop4 uses CMake as its default build system.  In CMake all libraries and other program elements are identified in special file (CMakeLists.txt).  That file then becomes the basis of the make file that actually builds the executable.

Comment: Could you add location of the default installation folder where this `CMakeLists.txt` resides?